# Git not tracking existing files in repo

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have no clue what else to do. I have looked all over stackoverflow and tried multiple solutions with no luck. Git will not track my existing files. I have reinstalled git as well as git desktop check gitconfig as well as remove gitignore. Cloning the exact same repo on my macbook pro works fine.

This is the repo im cloning: https://github.com/DevonJerothe/ED-Discovery.git

note cloning in android studio also doesnt work.

git status shows no changes even after changing, deleting. Only new files added are tracked but nothing in the file, only the creation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try first to change a file, confirm that `git status` does not pick that change, and do a

```
git check-ignore -v -- file/you/just/changed.
```

That way, you will see if there is any global exclude/gitignore file which would be, on Windows, responsible for ignoring your local changes.